# Why is RND in my vbscript seem to be repeating

Tags: vbscript

I know that computers cannot make truly random numbers but this is an obvious pattern. I made a code that uses `rnd` to make a random number 
`(RAND = Int((max - min + 1) * Rnd + min) )` and when I activate it 3 times here is what happens

1.

```
TILst
YaX1U
cA5Zy
!5d0x
IXdME
```

2.

```
TILst
YaX1U
cA5Zy
!5d0x
IXdME
```

3.

```
TILst
YaX1U
cA5Zy
!5d0x
IXdME
```

It repeated itself 3 times, on three different attempts can anyone explain and/or help me fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e566zd96%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to
>   initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system
>   timer.

Demo:

```
Randomize
WScript.Echo Rnd()
```

Output (with Randomize):

```
cscript 32911108.vbs && cscript 32911108.vbs && cscript 32911108.vbs
0,5855066
0,1580774
0,2203943
```

Output (without Randomize):

```
cscript 32911108.vbs && cscript 32911108.vbs && cscript 32911108.vbs
0,7055475
0,7055475
0,7055475
```

Comment: thank you this fixed it perfectly.here are some truly random words:CDRGX
HF4!j
grp5J
qvNYt
@0NQC

Comment: @TheGamerLord Amazing what happens when you read documentation.